# How to use jsoup to select an element which is generated by javascript

Tags: html, jsoup, element, document

I am using jsoup to parse an URL that has a form which is generated by java script.
When i use firefox to browse that URL and open page source code. i dont see the form element in html code but in attached java script.

Now, i want to select that form element. how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: In Jsoup you can't.

Jsoup is just a parser with some added convenience functionality in network access to get the html content. Jsoup is not a browser and it does not know JavaScript.

Solution:

You should look into [selenium webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/), which remote controls a real browser. This should have no problems generating the form. The selenium java bindings offer an API similar to Jsoup to access the content.